# GROUP BY for MAX and NULL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want max `startdate` but there is a `NULL` data, it will be null.

Sample data is as follows:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Id INT, StartDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES (1, NULL),
(1, '2016.07.30'),
(1, '2016.07.05'),
(1, '2016.07.05'),
(2, '2016.07.07'),
(2, '2016.07.05'),
(3, '2016.07.05'),
(3, NULL)
```

My Query:

```
SELECT Id, MAX(StartDate) AS StartDate
FROM @Tbl
GROUP BY Id
```

Output:

```
Id          StartDate
----------- ----------
1           2016-07-30
2           2016-07-07
3           2016-07-05
```

Desired Output:

```
Id          StartDate
----------- ----------
1           NULL
2           2016-07-07
3           NULL
```

Comment: Just for fun: `dateadd(day, nullif(sign(count(*)-count(StartDate)), 1), max(StartDate))`

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem we can use a `count` function that behave different in two cases:

1. when we use `count(*)` then all rows are count (also with null value)
2. when we use `count(someFieldName)` then only rows with not null value are count

You can see this different behaviour on this example using sample data from the question

```
select Id, count(*) as count_all, count(StartDate) as count_StartDate
from @Tbl
group by Id;
```

On the output we can see this

```
Id  count_all   count_StartDate
1   4           3
2   2           2
3   2           1
```

We can use this different behaviour to solve problem from question by this query

```
select Id, case when count(*) = count(StartDate) 
                then max(StartDate) 
                else null 
                end as StartDate
from @Tbl
group by Id
```

On the output we can see the desired result

```
Id  StartDate
1   NULL
2   2016-07-07 00:00:00.000
3   NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the result.

```
SELECT Id, CASE 
                WHEN MAX(COALESCE(StartDate, '2099.01.01')) = '2099.01.01'  THEN NULL 
                ELSE MAX(StartDate) END AS StartDate
FROM @Tbl
GROUP BY Id
```